# Split dataframe into n equal time intervals, to groupby, where time interval is (time.max() - time.min())/ n

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe which I want to split into 5 chunks (more generally n chunks), so that I can apply a groupby on the chunks.

I want the chunks to have equal time intervals but in general each group may contain different numbers of records.

Let's call the data

```
s = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2012-1-1', periods=100, freq='D'))
```

and the timeinterval `ti = (s.max() - s.min())/n`

So the first chunk should include all rows with dates between `s.min()` and `s.min() + ti`, the second, all rows with dates between `s.min() + ti` and `s.min() + 2*ti`, etc.

Can anyone suggest an easy way to achieve this?  If somehow I could convert all my dates into seconds since the epoch, then I could do something like `thisgroup = floor(thisdate/ti)`.

Is there an easy 'pythonic' or 'panda-ista' way to do this?

Thanks very much (and Merry Christmas!),

Robin

Comment: wouldn't `np.floor((ts - ts.min( )) / (ts.max( ) - ts.min( )) * n)` work?

Comment: Yes - that does work - thank you very much.  However, I'm confused:  I was attempting to do: `ts["bin"] = np.floor(ts["date"] - ts["date"].min( )) / (ts["date"].max( ) - ts["date"].min( ))` which errors with a  `TypeError: can only operate on a timedeltas for addition and subtraction, but the operator [__truediv__] was passed`, even though `ts["bin"] = np.floor((ts - ts.min( )) / (ts.max( ) - ts.min( )))` works.  What's the difference?!

Comment: operating with timedeltas like that requires numpy 1.7.1 and most likey pandas 0.13/master (0.13rc1 is out). some types of operations will work on 0.12, but not division of timedeltas (which is what your denomincator is). see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#time-deltas-conversions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as follows:

```
s = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2012-1-1', periods=20, freq='D'), columns=["date"])

n = 5

s["date"] = np.int64(s)  #This step may not be needed in future pandas releases
s["bin"] = np.floor((n-0.001)*(s["date"] - s["date"].min( )) /((s["date"].max( ) - s["date"].min( ))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.array_split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> s = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2012-1-1', periods=10, freq='D'))

>>> np.array_split(s, 5)
[0   2012-01-01 00:00:00
1   2012-01-02 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns], 2   2012-01-03 00:00:00
3   2012-01-04 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns], 4   2012-01-05 00:00:00
5   2012-01-06 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns], 6   2012-01-07 00:00:00
7   2012-01-08 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns], 8   2012-01-09 00:00:00
9   2012-01-10 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]]

>>> np.array_split(s, 2)
[0   2012-01-01 00:00:00
1   2012-01-02 00:00:00
2   2012-01-03 00:00:00
3   2012-01-04 00:00:00
4   2012-01-05 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns], 5   2012-01-06 00:00:00
6   2012-01-07 00:00:00
7   2012-01-08 00:00:00
8   2012-01-09 00:00:00
9   2012-01-10 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  That doesn't quite do what I'm after.  Suppose there were 100 records on the first day and one 2 records on the second day, and I wanted to split this into `n=2` chunks, I'd want the first chunk to contain 100 records, and the second to contain 2 records.  The thing I'm struggling with is when the time interval is not something standard like a day or hour.